# JavaScript, inherited function is printed out as undefined

Tags: javascript, json, oop, stringify

I am wondering why `JSON.stringify(this.Master.Func)` returns 'undefined' instead of `function() { ... }`.

Function itself executes by adding `()`.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t4ngY/

**CODE**

```
var $ = {}; // some global

var Master = 
    {
        property: 'Property',

        Func: function()
        {
            console.log('I am Func inside Master');
        },

        PassToGlobal: function()
        {
            $.master = this;
        }
    };

Master.PassToGlobal();

var Slave =
    {
        Master: $.master,

        ShowFunc: function()
        {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.Master.Func)); //returns undef
            this.Master.Func(); //prints `I am Func inside Master`
        }
    }

Slave.ShowFunc();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any possibility to have JSON.stringify preserve functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759200/is-there-any-possibility-to-have-json-stringify-preserve-functions)

Comment: try `(new Slave).ShowFunc();`

Answer (score 0):

if you want see function text you can simply call `toString` method like this

```
console.log(this.Master.Func.toString());
```