# Converting Object to String in JS with JSON.stringify causes function tobe removed in String format

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

I want to convert full object to String in JS.

The Object is as below :-

{
parent : {
            "a":1, 
            testFunc(){ return 2;} 
         } 
}

When i use 
`JSON.stringify({parent : {"a":1, testFunc(){ return 2;} } })`

**-Actual :-** 
I get **"{"parent":{"a":1}}"** as the output

**- Expected :-**

but i wanted output as **"{"parent":{"a":1,testFunc(){return 2;}}}"**

Is there any way to keep the function's in string as JSON.stringify removes the function.

Comment: `JS Object != JSON`

Comment: This is expected. Functions are removed from the output string. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759200/is-there-any-possibility-to-have-json-stringify-preserve-functions

Comment: *"A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array."* https://www.json.org/

Comment: you need to parse it in to JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(str); where you will get complete string in json object