# Refactoring javascript string config

Tags: javascript, string, config

I have a huge string config in a file and i want to refactor it to have intelisense.
Note there are also variables in it, so using a function would be the best option.
The result of the return function should be exactly what's inside the config string.

```
  const existingConfig = `
  var configOptions =  {
    enableProp: true,
    style: "plain",
    onReady: function() {
        return true
    }
  }
    `;
```

I tried something like:

```
  const newConfig = (val) => {
    return {
      enableProp: true,
      style: val,
      onReady: function() {
        return true
      }
    };
  };
  const res = JSON.stringify(newConfig());
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why does it have to be a string with JS code in it? Why not take the JSON you already have as `res` and use that? Then it'd be as simple as `var configOptions = JSON.parse(res)` and you have plain objects at the end.

Comment: It's a 3-rd party  library config and that's the only way it works.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(newConfig())` will not produce same result, as there is no functions inside JSON (so you will get plain `"onReady": true` inside json) and all keys and values will be surrounded by quotes.

Comment: To answer your question: `const res = "var configOptions = " + JSON.stringify(newConfig())`

Comment: @Justinas I missed the function being there. They are completely omitted from JSON, so it's not going to be `"onReady": true` it will just not exist.

Comment: @CristianMuscalu this sounds horrifying

Comment: @VLAZ not as horrifying as working with a string of 700 line javascript config :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any possibility to have JSON.stringify preserve functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759200/is-there-any-possibility-to-have-json-stringify-preserve-functions)

Comment: @CristianMuscalu that's the exact part I was picturing as horrifying. Well, juggling JS code as a string more generally.

Comment: This is the widget documentation: https://docs.oppwa.com/tutorials/integration-guide/customisation?id=B9E2E69D4649234E821D5520FC049B34.uat01-vm-tx02&resourcePath=%2Fv1%2Fcheckouts%2FB9E2E69D4649234E821D5520FC049B34.uat01-vm-tx02%2Fpayment

Comment: @Justinas i read the answer you posted, but i don't see how i could use it. Do you have an example maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about

```js
let configString = (() => {

  var configOptions =  {
    enableProp: true,
    style: "plain",
    onReady: function() {
        return true
    }
  };

}).toString();

configString = configString.slice(
  configString.indexOf("{")+1, 
  configString.lastIndexOf("}")
);

console.log(configString);
```

You could also do `.toString().replace(/^.*?\{|\}.*?$/g, "");` but I don't like it, because the `}.*$` part could mean a lot of backtracking. I'm not sure how well it behaves with 700 lines of JS probably containing a lot of `}`.

Comment: This is pretty cool and it works on a first try. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why the `indexOf`/`lastIndexOf` action at all. The curly brackets should be at the same place every time. The indexes may as well be static.

Comment: @VLAZ because I'm not sure about that. If the formatting is stable across browsers/engines. If it is stable, then you're right.