# importing and parsing string config

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, webpack

I'm trying to convert a js config to string, but i'm having a **problem with the imported values.**
Please check the desired output below.

[Codesandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-brook-bggis9?file=/src/App.js:0-456)
This is a follow-up question to this: [Refactoring javascript string config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73551894/refactoring-javascript-string-config/73557455#73557455)

```
import { TEST } from "./config";

export default function App() {
  let configString = (() => {
    var configOptions = {
      message: TEST.Success
    };
  }).toString();

  configString = configString.slice(
    configString.indexOf("{") + 1,
    configString.lastIndexOf("}")
  );

  return <p>{configString}</p>;
}
```

OUTPUT:
var configOptions = { message: _config.TEST.Success };

DESIRED OUTPUT:
var configOptions = { message: Success };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of casting everything into a string and then do (rather complex) transformations on that string, I'd suggest to convert the configuration *keys and values* into a string and add the  `{` and `}` afterwards:

```
import { TEST } from "./config";


function objToString(obj) {
  // creates a string in the format 'key: value, key2: value2, etc...'
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce(
    (cstring, [key, value]) => {
      return cstring !== ''
        ? `${cstring}, ${key}: ${value}`
        : `${key}: ${value}`
    },
    ''
  );
}


export default function App() {
  const variable = "w00t";

  let configString = objToString({
    enableProp: true,
    style: "plain",
    onReady: function () {
      return true;
    },
    message: TEST.Success,
    variable
  });

  console.log(configString);

  return (<p>{`{${configString}}`}</p>); // <-- note the added {} to the front/end
}
```

Comment: Any idea for this case? https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-goldberg-scsvyq?file=/src/App.js