# Javascript JSON.stringify function is not working

Tags: javascript, json, browser, javascript-engine

I have tried to convert a JS object into JSON.

```
JSON.stringify({a:1, toJSON: function(){}})
```

Native JSON stringify is not working as expected. JSON stringify executes toJSON function in JS object internally. I have overwritten native code as follows,

```
// Adding try catch for non JSON support browsers.
try{
 _jsonStringify = JSON.stringify;
 JSON.stringify = function(object){
    var fnCopy = object.toJSON; 
    object.toJSON = undefined;
    var result =  _jsonStringify(object);
    object.toJSON = fnCopy;
    return result;      
 };
}catch(e){}
```

It is working fine. is there any other better way to do this?. is there any specific reason in native code execute **toJSON** function in input object?

Comment: You should use [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) for browsers that do not support `JSON.stringify`

Comment: My questions are still pending ('is there any specific reason in native code execute toJSON function in input object?`). If anybody know reason, please update this thread.

Comment: It's so you can customize the serialization. I've updated my answer with an example for you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because `JSON.stringify` will return the return value of the `toJSON` function if it exists ([Source](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js#L234)).

For example:

```
JSON.stringify({a:1, toJSON: function(){ return "a"; }});
```

Will return:

```
"a"
```

This behaviour is [described on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior). The reason for this is so that you can customize the behaviour of the serialization. For example, say I only want to serialize the IDs of the `Animal` class in this example. I could do the following:

```
var Animal = function(id, name) {
    this.AnimalID = id;
    this.Name     = name;
};

Animal.prototype.toJSON = function() {
    return this.AnimalID;
};

var animals = [];

animals.push(new Animal(1, "Giraffe"));
animals.push(new Animal(2, "Kangaroo"));

JSON.stringify(animals); // Outputs [1,2]
```

If you do not want this behaviour then your current method works well; however, I would recommend not overwriting the behaviour of `JSON.stringify`, but rather name your method something else. An external library might be using the `toJSON` function in an object and it could lead to unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks @dhsto, I think I have to go through the code in https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js (link in your answer).

Comment: @hilarudeens I wouldn't bother if I were you. I would just use the method you use in your question, but name your new function something else other than `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: I agree. Override native is not good practice. Hopefully, this is going to be good starting point for other developer who wants to drill down this further.

Comment: Nice answer. I agree.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the native `JSON.stringify` doesn't work is because it can't stringify functions. By setting the only function, `toJSON`, to undefined, JSON.stringify returns the proper value. See this question for more details: [JSON.stringify function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754919/json-stringify-function)

If you're trying to remove functions entirely, you can do this:

```
JSON.stringify(object, function(key, value) {
  if (typeof value === "function") {
    return undefined;
  }
  return value;
});
```

Comment: Thanks dude, However my question is different. On executing `JSON.stringify({a:1, toJSON: function(){}})`, I am expecting `{"a":1}`.

Comment: It is not working. I have tried `JSON.stringify({a:1, toJSON: function(){ return "Hello"; }}, function(key, value) {
  debugger;
  if (typeof value === "function") {
    return undefined;
  }
  return value;
});` in chrome. Have you run this code?

Answer (score -2):

The `JSON.stringify` function is usually invoked with one parameter, which is the object you want to serialize to JSON string. I believe there's a second optional parameter, which is a function that replaces one or more properties' way of serialization.

However, you should **not** add a function as a second property of your object!

When trying the following in Chrome's console:

```
JSON.stringify({a:1,b:'hello'})
```

This is the result:

```
"{"a":1,"b":"hello"}"
```

Comment: Sorry my question is different.  On executing `JSON.stringify({a:1, toJSON: function(){}})`, I am expecting `{"a":1}` which is not working.