# Sending function as argument results in undefined

Tags: typescript

```
broker.onTopic = function onTopic(topic: string, callback: Function): void {
    log.debug(`Callback to add: ${JSON.stringify(callback, null, 4)}`);
    //...more code
```

Somewhere else in my code:

```
interface ACPOSObject {
    data: State;
}
interface State {
    state: string;
}
broker.onTopic('[A-Z0-9]+/[A-Z0-9]+/[A-Z0-9]+/LINE/[A-Z]+/ACPOS', function onCenterline(
    topic: string,
    message: ACPOSObject
): void {
    log.debug(`New message in to topic: ${topic} message: ${message}`);
```

Logs show this:

```
2019-09-02T13:29:59.370Z debug: Callback to add: undefined
```

Why is the callback `undefined`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `JSON.stringify` [omits the functions by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description).

See [JSON.stringify function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754919/json-stringify-function) to find a way to handle the function. Basically, you need to use a replacer function to customize the "stringifying" process.

Comment: Argh you are completely correct, I totally forgot that it changes the object, I was expecting it to just return a new serialized string. Hence I forgot about toString(), derp.

Comment: Sometimes the brain just gets stuck on the most obvious things and you can't move on no matter what - I know that feel ;) Anyway, glad I could help.