# Stringify Native Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, serialization

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754919/json-stringify-function), the common way to save an object containing a function in JavaScript/Node.js is to serialize the functions in that object, i.e. convert them to strings.

However, using this approach approach, I ran into some issues. First of all it relies on `eval` or `new Function()`, which have obvious security and performance implications. The second issue is, that this does not work for references to native functions. For instance, `Math.sin.toString()` would return:

```
function sin() {
    [native code]
}
```

Which is useless for solving this problem, because it can neither be executed, nor reconstructed in any meaningful way, i.e. such that it references the original `Math` object.

For reference, here is a simplified example of an object I want to save to a JSON:

```
{
    hello: 'world',
    function1: () => {return 'this is a custom function';},
    function2: Math.random,
    function3: Math.sin
}
```

The ideal solution would:

1. Not serialize the function itself if possible, but save references to variables in the environment, like `Math.sin`; it could be converted back to `window['Math']['sin']`
2. Not rely on `eval` or `new Function()` for improved security

If anyone knows how I can serialize the references themselves, and traverse up to the last object in the window it would be greatly appreciated. Other ideas are also welcome.

Edit: I am saving the JSON to the local filesystem, not sending it to another server. So in theory I could use any format other than JSON as well, such as a JS file, or a binary file. However, I am not sure if this will solve the problem. I am also not concerned with the user editing the file, just with avoiding code injection.

Although not essential to the question, the file is supposed to store the hyperparameters of AI models, which can include mathematical functions (that may also be native like `tanh`).

Comment: You can't, and even with JavaScript (non-native) function that approach can fail in many ways. If, for example, the property value is a function that was created by another function and has a closure context, you won't have any access to that, and re-creating on the other side won't result in a working function.

Comment: The simple answer is that you should only be passing data between clients and servers, not code.

Comment: Also, the referenced question is from a confused person trying to do something completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Pointy I agree that the approach I linked to is not great, that is why I would prefer to save the references only. I thought this might be possible with a trick I do not know of.

Comment: Well JSON is a *serialization scheme* for data transmission. The other end of the connection might be a different programming language. Sending anything other then the basic and (nearly) universal data types in the JSON spec would make no sense for JSON in general. Yes, you can stringify functions, but that's stepping out of the design context for the format.

Comment: There is never a good reason to send *code* between systems. It's an open door for malicious code injection.

Comment: @trincot I am saving the JSON to the local filesystem. However, that does not guarantee a user might not modify the saved files.

Comment: Please edit your question and explain the reason, the goal for all of this, so that someone can suggest what you should do instead to reach the seem high level goals. For instance, if your code is to read the content from local storage later, then why would you store code? Your code already has that code...

Answer (score 0):

First things first, it's an absolutely terrible idea to do this and it will come back to bite you in the future.  One option would be to test the serialized function string using RegEx:

```js
function getNativeFunctionName(string) {
  const nativeMatch = /^function (.*?)\(\) \{ \[native code\] \}$/;
  const result = nativeMatch.exec(string)?.[1];
  return result ?? false;
}
```

Followed by either using eval on your string if it's not native, or using a prebuilt lookup object if it is.  Something along the lines of:

```js
const nativeLookup = {
  abs: Math.abs,
  sin: Math.sin,
  parseInt: Number.parseInt,
  isNaN: Number.isNaN,
  decodeURIComponent: decodeURIComponent
  /* ... */
};

const nativeName = getNativeFunctionName(string);
const targetFunction = nativeName ? nativeLookup[nativeName] : eval(string);
```

Use the replacer argument on `JSON.stringify()` to implement the above logic and it should accomplish what you're trying to achieve.

Take note that while this works for static methods and immediate globals, implementing this for instantiated dynamic objects and/or object prototypes is an unimaginable undertaking, even worse if meta programming is at play on the pre-serialized side of things.

To address the other bit in your question, if you have a separate need to walk up the namespace chain you can use values in your lookup such as `sin: ['sin', 'Math']` and assume the `globalThis` value at the end.